# Does HTML5 canvas API work without adding element to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm drawing frames from an HTML5 video element to a canvas like this:

```js
const wrapperElement = document.getElementById('wrapper')
const videoElement = document.getElementById('video')
  
videoElement.onloadeddata = function () {
  const width = videoElement.videoWidth
  const height = videoElement.videoHeight

  const canvasElement = document.createElement('canvas')  
  canvasElement.width = width
  canvasElement.height = height

  wrapperElement.appendChild(canvasElement) // is this necessary?

  const ctx = canvasElement.getContext('2d')
  ctx.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, width, height)

  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height) // what I need!
  
  // doing something with imageData
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <video id="video" loop autoplay muted>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
  <br />
</div>
```

I only need the canvas to get my hands on the raw image data, since the video element API does not provide a method like `getImageData`. Therefore I don't want the canvas to be visible on my page. I know I can achieve this by making it `display: none` but I was wondering if it has to be present in the DOM at all. Wouldn't it be enough to just create the canvas via JavaScript and then use it's API? It seems to work for me in Chrome 63. I'm hesitating though because any tutorial using this pattern also always inserts the canvas in the DOM.

Comment: No you don't need to append the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm hesitating though because any tutorial using this pattern also always inserts the canvas in the DOM.

Yes, you can safely use canvas without inserting it into the DOM tree. The DOM provide a way to actually *show* the content of the canvas, but is not needed to process its content.

(Tuts probably assume you actually want to see what goes on with the canvas.)